# Controlling division precision

Tags: matlab, precision

Consider the following simple division:

```
A=8.868;
A/0.1
ans =
  88.679999999999993
```

This results in a small mistake, due to floating point precision. Is there any way to prevent this from happening? Basically all I'm doing is shifting the comma one position, whilst not being close to the maximum number of allowable digits in MATLAB.

I would like to obtain a result as:

```
A/0.1
ans =
  88.68
```

where trailing zeros are of no concern, as long as they are zero only, and not contain some number at the 14th digit or so.

Interestingly this issue also pops up when rounding to `N` digits:

```
R = (randi([8659 49847],[1e3 1]))/1e3;
xmin = min(R);
el = 0.1;
step = 1/el;
tmp1=xmin/el;
tmp2=round(tmp1);
tmp3=round(tmp2*el,3);

tmp3 =
   8.699999999999999
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why that way? why not multiply by 10?

Comment: @AnderBiguri because that is in my case my grid size in centimetre, meaning that it can also be e.g. 0.25, 0.12 or whatever the customer wants.

Comment: @AnderBiguri `A*10` is also imprecise in this case...

Comment: But the issue will always be there. It is not because you loose precision for doing floating point arithmetic, its because you can not store the number you want in float. You could always store it as an int or char with info about the amount of decimal places, but once you convert to float, youll lose that accuracy. the problem is that it is impossible to store `88.68` in memory as a float.

Comment: http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/ Check this for more info

Comment: Trying `format long; 88.68` also illustrates this point as it returns `88.680000000000007`

Comment: Also consider `vpa`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using symbolic math, you can get precise results:

```
x=sym('8.868')/sym('.1')
```

Comment: How does this work in terms of speed? Since I have some 800M data points, speed is an important issue.

Comment: Symbolic math is very slow, probably impossible for such data sizes.

Answer (score 5):

You can always use [fixed point](http://sigpromu.org/brett/elec3730/lecture12.pdf) arithmetics where the slope is a multiple of 10. You won't have any inaccuracies when you multiply/divide by ten. In Matlab, you can use [Fixed Point Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/index.html)

**Edit:** Following your comment - it looks like you can set the slope to be 0.05.

Comment: As I pointed out in [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33754807/controlling-division-precision#comment55277249_33754807) the slope won't always be a multiple of 10.

Comment: @Adriaan, can you find the common multiple of what the slope can be? Otherwise, you can always use infinite precision math.

Comment: My data is millimetre precision data, i.e. three digits, which I want to bin in grid of X cm, where X is determined by the resolution the customer requires. Usually X is 0.1, 0.25 or 0.5 m, thus that's what the data needs to be rounded to.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is only posted for completeness in my case.

---

I circumvented the issue somewhat in my case using the third output of `unique`:

```
el = 0.25;
A = (randi([7364 84635],[1e4 1]))/1e3;
B = A/el;
C = round(B);
D = C*el;
[tmp1,tmp2,tmp3] = unique(D);
E = tmp1(tmp3,:);
all(E==D)
ans = 
     1
```

which does the binning correctly. So even though the centre points might not be exact with infinite precision, they are within at least some 10 digits, which is more than the 3 digit precision of my original data.

Answer (score 3):

You can represent your numbers as fractions of integers. As long as you do not convert to float, you do not lose precision:

```
A = 8.868;
div = 0.1;
[N1,D1] = rat(A);
[N2,D2] = rat(div);
% divide A by div:
N = N1 * D2;
D = N2 * D1;
```

Of course your numbers might be not precise to begin with, as mentioned in other answers/comments. The conversion to fractions can also introduce approximation, but that depends on the numbers you deal with and the `tol` parameter to `rat`.